# Robot Framework - How to skip the "please accept cookies" popup?

Tags: python, cookies, robotframework, session-cookies

Is there a cookie setting I can add to the session so that websites don't show those annoying "please accept our cookies" popups? Or are they all unique and there's no way to make a generic cookie value for it?

Comment: They are all unique per site, in short.

Comment: You can simply click on accept or  ok button, it can be identified as xpath, or class

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping there was a setting you could pass when opening a browser, but this will have to do

Answer (score -1):

Robot Framework does not support it. You gonna need to develop your own Key Work or lib in order to perform it